# Calling a func from one class in another class - swift

Tags: ios, xcode, function, swift

I have a class `viewcontroller`.  In another class, `SigViewController`, I have a function which captures an image of a signature.  I would like to call the function in the `viewcontroller` class (specifically in an IBAction).

In `viewcontroller` I have the following.

```
@IBAction func sigsave(sender: AnyObject) {
    SigViewController().getSignature()
}
```

In `SigViewController` the function is...

```
func getSignature() ->UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width,
        self.bounds.size.height))
    self.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    var signature: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    println("saved image")
    return signature
}
```

The `viewcontroller` is returning the error `Use of unresolved identifier SigViewController.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It does not seem that function `getSignature()`  is an instance method of UIViewController Class.Show the class this function in.

Answer (score 1):

`getSignature()` is an instance function so you need to make an instance of `SigViewController` class to call it. You can call class functions in another class using the syntax `ClassName.FunctionName()` if you mark the function as a class function. But when you do that you don't have access to any non class level instance variables.

Regular functions are like - methods in Objective-C, class functions are like + functions.

Comment: Thanks so much for commenting, however I don't think I know enough about swift to follow enough.  I read some Apple documentation and messed around with some public/internal classes but all my efforts still produced errors.  Basically I'm not sure what you mean by "make an instance of SigViewController class to call it".

Comment: If you haven't come across creating objects from classes yet, I would really recommend having a look at *The Swift Programming Language* (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) , it's totally free and will take you through everything you need to know to get started! And it will make you much more productive if you know what you're doing instead of just messing around with it.